# Web Deploy Package containing output from Web Application and Database Project

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, database-project, webdeploy-3.5

In my organization the main product is a web application and an associated database. Both the web application and database is source controlled in TFS. We are running this product in various versions across hundres of IIS web site instances. When having that many web site instances on IIS deployment is atm. a problem.

What I want to do is to package my web application together with the output from my database project. I've been looking into creating a Web Deploy Package which makes it easy to deploy a web application remotely, locally or programitically to IIS if i want to.
What I want to achieve is to have one package but I want to know if it's possible to embed a Database project into a Web Deploy Package taking advantages of dacpac incremental database deployment?
If this is not possible is there any good alternatives to Web Deploy Package that suit my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to create an MSI package to deploy both the Web Deploy Package and also update the DBs. For example, with Advanced Installer you can use the [built-in support for Web Deploy Packages](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/web-deploy.html).

To perform dacpac incremental database deployment you can call [SqlPackage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) from the same MSI, [as a custom action](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#custact). The linked example shows a simple EXE running, but you can change that to run any desired EXE, passing your required command line parameters.

If you perform frequent upgrades of the websites, or the settings are usually changed after the installation/deployment, then you should take a look at the next thread too, it talks about [persisting website installations during upgrades](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18477).